# CSS, not working on IE 7

Tags: css

http://www.aspiredesigns.com.sg/ this web site works good in Chrome, Firefox, IE8+ 
But in IE 7 it doesn't

Could someone provide hint where to search etc.

Greetings

Comment: Try oDesk for that way formed questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers handle css differently or not at all. IE7 for example handles it quite poorly compared to modern browsers.

There are charts you can look up to see what rules which browsers support and which don't. Here are two links to get you started:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html 
http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css